# openpyxl: conditionally formatting with COUNTIF

Tags: python, openpyxl, conditional-formatting

I am using openpyxl to create an Excel sheet that I need to conditionally format based on if a certain text string is found within a cell. For example, I want to see if a cell begins with `"ok:"`, so my equation is `=COUNTIF(A1,"ok:*")>0`. This works in Excel. However, the following Python code in openpyxl results in Excel saying the sheet is corrupted:

```py
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='EE1111', end_color='EE1111', fill_type='solid')
ws.conditional_formatting.add('E1:E10', FormulaRule(formula=['=COUNTIF(A1,"ok:*")>0'],fill=redFill))
```

How do I properly add a `COUNTIF` condition to an excel sheet with openpyxl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't use `COUNTIF`. Here is the code that works:

```py
red_text = Font(color="9C0006")
red_fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE")
dxf = DifferentialStyle(font=red_text, fill=red_fill)
rule = Rule(type="containsText", operator="containsText", text="highlight", dxf=dxf)
rule.formula = ['NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("ok:*",A1)))']
wsNonDebug.conditional_formatting.add('A1:F40', rule)
```